# Scrolling chart in Excel or Powerpoint 2007/2010

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, activex

I have a chart which has large number of points on X-axis.(e.g. ECG).

How do I put this chart as a **horizontally scrollable** object in Powerpoint 2007/2010?
If i just paste it, it gets resized to fit width and becomes unreadable.

I want to maintain the height by including a horizontal scroll bar for chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not **sure** if that can be done. Having said that I can give you an interesting alternative. :)

Let's say our chart looks like this in Excel

[image]

Right click on the chart and click on `Copy`. Open Ms Paint and paste that picture. Save that picture, say as `C:\MyChart.Jpg`

Next open MS Powerpoint and navigate to the `Developer` Tab. (**See Snapshot**) In the developer tab, click on additional controls button and select "Microsoft Web Browser" and insert that control in your respective slide. Size it accordingly. Also place a Command Button. Name it `Show Chart` or anything else what you feel is right :)

[image]

Double click on the command button and paste this code there

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "C:\MyChart.jpg"
End Sub
```

Now press `F5` to run the presentation. Your screen will look like this.

[image]

When you press the command button, you will get what you wanted :)

[image]

**DISADVANTAGES OF THIS METHOD**

1) You cannot edit the chart in MS Powerpoint. You will have to do that in Excel and repeat the entire procedure to save it as an image.

2) You cannot distribute your PPT. You will have to send the image separately with the PPT and also you will have to change the command button code (*assuming that PPT and image stay in the same folder*) to

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate ActivePresentation.Path & "\MyChart.jpg"
End Sub
```

**OR**

You will have to embed the xls file in the ppt and write a complex code to extract the chart from the excel file and save it to the users `temp directory`. You can then use that image in the `Webbrowser1`

Comment: Thanks. It's the thought that counts ;)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Thanks!
But, redistribution is exactly what I want.
And It's not possible for me to have the image as a separate file(I am to give this to my customer).

One more thing, can we insert excel sheet/chart as an ActiveX object in powerpoint?

Comment: @Siddarth: another beautiful post.  tumchaaditya, yes you can insert an excel sheet or chart as an ActiveX object, but that's what you get when you copy/paste Excel objects onto slides in PPT, and you already know that won't suit your purposes.  And by the way, if your audience uses the free PPT viewer, even pasted Excel objects may not work; the viewer doesn't support ActiveX/OLE/Whatever we're calling it this week.

Comment: @tumchaaditya: I added a new post. Please download the file and check if it runs :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this approached the problem from a different angle, I am posting an entirely new answer :)

This method follows up on my last comment

> > > You will have to embed the xls file in the ppt and write a complex code to extract the chart from the excel file and save it to the users temp directory. You can then use that image in the Webbrowser1

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > @Siddharth Rout: Thanks! But, redistribution is exactly what I want. And It's not possible for me to have the image as a separate file(I am to give this to my customer).

Your worries should not worry you anymore ;)

**DESIGN MODE**

In powerpoint slide insert the Excel Object which has the chart. Your slide should look like this

[image]

Now as shown in my other answer, insert a "Microsoft Web Browser" and "Command Button". Place the Webbrowser above the Excel Object to hide it.

Your screen should look like this now.

[image]

Paste this code and run your presentation... That's it... Really ;)

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" _
(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Dim ImageFile As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ExtractToTemp
    WebBrowser1.Navigate ImageFile
End Sub

Sub ExtractToTemp()
    Dim oSl As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape

    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLWB As Object, oXLSht As Object
    Dim mychart As Object

    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

    Set oSh = oSl.Shapes(1)

    With oSh.OLEFormat.Object.Sheets(1)
        .Shapes(1).Copy
    End With

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oXLApp.Visible = False

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLWB = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set oXLSht = oXLWB.Worksheets(1)

    oXLSht.Paste

    '~~> Save Picture Object
    ImageFile = TempPath & "Tester.jpg"

    If Len(Dir(ImageFile)) > 0 Then Kill ImageFile

    Set mychart = oXLSht.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    mychart.Export FileName:=ImageFile, FilterName:="jpg"

    '~~> Wait till the file is saved
    Do
        If FileExists(ImageFile) = True Then Exit Do
        DoEvents
    Loop

    '~~> Clean Up And Close Excel
    oXLWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    oXLApp.Quit

    Set oXLWB = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing
End Sub

'~~> Get User's TempPath
Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function

'~~> Function tot check if file exists
Public Function FileExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
Whoa:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**SAMPLE FILE FOR TESTING** : Please download this file and run the presentation. If you see the chart after clicking the button then it means it works :)

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=cdd3f8abe20bbe3b&resid=CDD3F8ABE20BBE3B!162&parid=root

Comment: I can't do it...
Macro throws an exception: OLEFormat(Unknown member): Invalid request. This property only applies to OLE objects.

Comment: Did you crate everything from the start or are you running my file?

Comment: I created everything from start. As specified on your blog article.

Comment: Which Windows Version are you using. Also which MS Office version are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Professionsl x64
Office 2007

Comment: Is that 64 bit Office or 32 Office?

Comment: I can send you the files created by me if you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10493/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-tumchaaditya)

Comment: I am sorry. But right now, I am in company and chat is blocked here. :(
Can I just send you my files for now?

Comment: sure you can :) Please zip them and upload them in wikisend.com and then share the link here :)

Comment: that website too is blocked! :(
in fact none of the file sharing websites will work here.
can you give me your email id?

Comment: I found a better way of doing it.
only thing is its completely in excel and I cant transcode it work in powerpoint.
I will send you the excel file on your hotmail id(which i got from your blog).